# My C# Code is giving error iF i pass more than 1 parameter

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am fetching data in gridview by this C# Code.
but it is giving me back my Pre-Defined error if i pass more than 1 Value as Asset number according to my Code.
If i pass Only 1 asset number at a time it works absolutely Fine.
Please Help.

```
private void UpdateAssetNumber (string requestId)
    {

        clsDatabase objDb = new clsDatabase();
        clsUtility objUtil = new clsUtility();
        SendEmail objMail = new SendEmail();
        SqlTransaction objTrans;

        string TableName = "Assets_Requisition_Detail_Controller";

        string FieldsName = string.Empty;
        string FieldsValue = string.Empty;
        string todayDate = objUtil.fncGetDate();
        bool flg = false;

        try
        {
            objDb.fncOpenConnection();
            objTrans = objDb.cnnConnection.BeginTransaction();

            FieldsName = "Asset_No$";
            foreach (GridViewRow row in grdEntry.Rows)
            {
                Label lblDetailId = row.FindControl("lblDetailId") as Label;
                TextBox txtAssetNo = row.FindControl("txtAssetNo") as TextBox;

                FieldsValue = "'" + txtAssetNo.Text + "'$'";
                flg = objDb.fncModifyRecord(TableName, FieldsName, FieldsValue, "Request_Id= " + requestId + " AND IsActive = 'TRUE' AND Detail_Id = " + lblDetailId.Text, ref objDb.cnnConnection, ref objTrans);
                if (!flg)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (flg)
            {
                flg = UpdateRquestStatus(lblPk.Text, ref objDb.cnnConnection, ref objTrans);
            }

            if (flg)
            {
                objTrans.Commit();
                SearchRequest();
                pnlNew.Visible = false;
                pnlSearch.Visible = true;
                lblMsg.Text = objUtil.fncGetErrorDesc(1);
                objMail.SendCodeOpenedEmail("ASSET", Convert.ToInt32(lblPk.Text));

            }
            else
            {
                objTrans.Rollback();
                lblMsg.Text = objUtil.fncGetErrorDesc(-1);
            }
            pnlMsg.Visible = true;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            objDb.fncCloseConnection(objDb.cnnConnection);
            objTrans = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is giving back my Pre-defined error for more than 1 asset number .

Comment: Pls include the error message in the question. Everyone is not going to look at comments.

Comment: Obviously, you declared `UpdateAssetNumber` is a function which takes 1 argument, it will take 1 argument only.

Comment: thanks Tareq, I will keep that in mind in future.

Comment: Thanks Danh, How can i make it work for multiple Asset numbers?
I am New to this thing.

Comment: Maybe your Convert.ToInt32(lblPk.Text) fails because your are passing it more than a single number

Comment: @Priyanshu the future is now.  You can edit your question, and you should.

Comment: @Priyanshu https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it from the caller without having to change this method or either having another UpdateAssetNumber method that get a list as parameter. Something like:

```
private void UpdateAssetNumber (List<string> requestIds)
{
     foreach(var requestId in requestIds)
     {
           UpdateAssetNumber(requestId)
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you identified only one input parameter

```
    private void UpdateAssetNumber (string requestId) {
```

Try

```
    private void UpdateAssetNumber(params string[] list) {
```